# Why does the native heap memory increases constantly on an orientation change?

Tags: android

I have made a demo activity. i.e a simple Activity with a layout and a TextView.

I have used

```
Log.e(kFileString, "Native Heap Allocated Size = "
    + Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize());
Log.e(kFileString, "Native Heap Free Size = "
    + Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize());
Log.e(kFileString, "Native Heap SIZE = " + Debug.getNativeHeapSize());
```

for logging the native heap assigned.

I noticed that each time I change the orientation the allocated native heap is increased.

Can someone please tell me why this happens and if there is any documentation about the Android native heap management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran a sample application and changed the orientation a couple of times with your log lines added in my `onCreate()`.

It kept allocation more and more Heap memory but once the Garbage Collector ran I was back to almost the same Heap size I started from.

Here is the log output:

```
12-22 15:35:04.403: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5720352
12-22 15:35:04.423: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 9952
12-22 15:35:04.433: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5730304
12-22 15:35:15.764: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5802312
12-22 15:35:15.764: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 9912
12-22 15:35:15.774: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5812224
12-22 15:35:19.558: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5821688
12-22 15:35:19.568: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 11016
12-22 15:35:19.568: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5832704
12-22 15:35:22.941: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5841120
12-22 15:35:22.941: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 12064
12-22 15:35:22.951: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5853184
12-22 15:35:25.243: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5860416
12-22 15:35:25.243: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 9152
12-22 15:35:25.243: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5869568
12-22 15:35:28.316: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5879752
12-22 15:35:28.316: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 10296
12-22 15:35:28.316: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5890048
12-22 15:35:30.568: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5899064
12-22 15:35:30.568: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 11464
12-22 15:35:30.568: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5910528
12-22 15:35:32.300: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5918416
12-22 15:35:32.300: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 12592
12-22 15:35:32.300: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5931008
12-22 15:35:34.262: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5937696
12-22 15:35:34.272: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 9696
12-22 15:35:34.282: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5947392
12-22 15:35:36.194: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5956976
12-22 15:35:36.204: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 10896
12-22 15:35:36.204: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5967872
12-22 15:35:37.455: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5976216
12-22 15:35:37.455: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 12136
12-22 15:35:37.455: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 5988352
12-22 15:35:39.387: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5995496
12-22 15:35:39.387: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 13336
12-22 15:35:39.387: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 6008832
12-22 15:35:41.129: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 6018880
12-22 15:35:41.139: D/dalvikvm(1606): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1769K, 51% free 4277K/8583K, external 4127K/5154K, paused 18ms+14ms
12-22 15:35:41.139: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 14528
12-22 15:35:41.139: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 6033408
12-22 15:35:47.055: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Allocated Size = 5829472
12-22 15:35:47.065: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap Free Size = 199840
12-22 15:35:47.065: D/ISA(15592): Native Heap SIZE = 6033408
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the DDMS tool from eclipse, go to the heap tab and select "Cause GC"
This will invoke the garbage collector, causing all of the unreferenced variables to be removed from the memory.
After that you can compare the memory with the initial state.

Regarding the memory increase during Activity recreation, it maybe cause due to
holding a reference to the previous activity, that prevents it from being garbage collected.
Make sure you don't have any static objects are referencing the activity directly or indirectly.

Answer (score -2):

You have memory leaks:

> When the screen orientation changes the system will, by default, destroy the current activity and create a new one while preserving its state. In doing so, Android will reload the application's UI from the resources. Now imagine you wrote an application with a large bitmap that you don't want to load on every rotation. The easiest way to keep it around and not having to reload it on every rotation is to keep in a static field:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Actually i have made the simplest app possible in andriod. This shouldn't cause leaks. I want to know the reason y is it happening. i.e native heap increases. Thanks for the reply.